# X11 apps have stopped working

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

I had been using gnuplot and nedit on my iMac running High Sierra. About 2 months ago they both stopped working. When I try to plot with Gnuplot i get the following error message:

```
gnuplot: unable to open display :0
gnuplot: X11 aborted.
```

When I try to run nedit I get:

```
NEdit: Can't open display
```

They both worked fine 2 months ago and I can think of nothing I've done to cause this. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this.

Comment: What is the value of DISPLAY in your end violent and have you set it. Have you changed shell startup files two moths ago. How do you start the programs?

Comment: when I type 'echo $DISPLAY', it returns :0.  I haven't changed startup shells. I'm still using bash.  I start nedit by just typing the nedit.  When I type 'gnuplot' the program starts fine but when I try to plot I get the error message.

Comment: How do you start X?  that value is wrong - so you set it?

Comment: X would start automatically. Or I suppose it did. I didn't do anything in the past to start it.

Comment: I just tried running 'Xquartz nedit' and a weird thing happened. Xquartz crashed and gave me the error screen which I can never read. I hit the reopen button and all of a sudden an xterm window opens,  Xquaetz is now running and all my apps work. Is there a way to issue the Xquartz command without it crashing?

Comment: What is in .xinitrc  and ,bashrc .bash_profile?

Comment: i have no ,xinitrc file.  .bash rc contains nothing of interest. .bash_profile contains line 'export DISPLAY=:0'..

Comment: Remove the DISPLAY line from.     .bash profile.

Comment: `Xquartz` sets the DISPLAY in the LaunchAgent- `/Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist`.

Comment: i removed the line from .bash_profile but it made no difference.  I still have to run 'Xquartz app_name'  and wait 5 secs for it to crash.  I click reopen at bottom of crash report and Xquartz starts and xterm opens. From that point on Xquartz stays open and my x-apps run fine.

Comment: Try adding the app commands in XQuartz's X11 Application Menu and running it from there. I have listed the step by step instructions in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362687/279727