# Display error when running NEdit

Tags: macos

I have a Mac Pro running macOS Mojave. I installed NEdit (using Homebrew). When I type `nedit` in the Terminal, I just get the message:

```
NEdit: Can't open display.
```

I am running bash. I check my display and I have indeed display :0

`echo $DISPLAY`

:0

I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: Is the X11 server running?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a display server running to run NEdit. Make sure that [NEdit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nedit/) is installed and configured correctly. Here's a step by step guide that you can follow to do so. This should work on any recent release of macOS. I have followed the steps on a Mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

1. Install XQuartz (display server) which NEdit requires to run. Run the following command to install XQuartz via Homebrew:

   `brew cask install xquartz`

   Skip if you already have it installed.
2. Install NEdit along with all of it's dependencies by running the following command:

   `brew install nedit`
3. After successfully installing the two, run XQuartz.app. You can find it under Other folder in Launchpad, in `/Applications/Utilities` folder in Finder, or simply via Spotlight search. Here's how to identify it:

   [image]
4. In the XQuartz Menu bar, click on Applications → Customize...

   [image]
5. You will be presented with X11 Application Menu window as shown:

   [image]
6. Click on Add Item button and create an entry for NEdit as shown:

   [image]
7. Now close the X11 Application Menu window. Go the XQuartz menu, click on Applications item and you'll see an entry named NEdit (the one you just created).

   [image]
8. Click on the entry to run NEdit :)

   [image]

Comment: Jmh might love to know you got this running on Mojave. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/330066/x11-apps-have-stopped-working

Comment: @bmike Not sure if it would be a good idea to mark that question as duplicate of this one? I'd rather not repost the answer.

Comment: Maybe ping in comments. No way there are dupe - this clearly can serve as you need X11. The other clearly had  X11 and then broke.

Answer (score 1):

Have a read of the home page for that package to see what other software it needs to run.

```
brew home nedit
```

Unless it can run in the terminal, you need a program to serve up display :0

Even once you have X11 [it still might not work.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/330066/x11-apps-have-stopped-working)

:0

Comment: Also, there are way more user friendly editor options that don’t require you to learn a lot, so try BBEdit for free from the App Store if you want an easy to run but powerful editor experience. It can launch from terminal, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue.
I followed all steps above about Xquartz, but it did not work from terminal, I still had the same error "Can't open display" message at nedit exec.

Then I finally obtained nedit opened on my mac by launching :

nedit -display :0

It worked for me.
You can alias the command now.